# eucledian distance between lists inside a list

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools, euclidean-distance, enumerate

I would like to calculate eucledian distance between lists inside a list and if that distance is smaller than threshold than get maximum element of such lists.

My solution gives me distance between each two lists, but I want to comapere every list with every other. Basically, a two loop solution probably.

```
yhat = [[10 , 15, 200 ,220], [20 , 25, 200 ,230], [30 , 15, 200 ,230], [100 , 150, 230 ,300], [110 , 150, 240 ,300] ]

def euclidean(v1, v2):
    return sum((p-q)**2 for p, q in zip(v1, v2)) ** .5

it = iter(yhat)
prev = next(it)
ec =[]
for ind, ele in enumerate(it):
    ec.append(euclidean(ele, prev))
    prev = ele
ec
```

To summarize, I would like a new list `xhat` which contains elements:

```
xhat = [[30 , 35, 200 ,230], [110 , 150, 240 ,300] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` and `itertools.combinations` to make this rather short:

```
from itertools import combinations

out = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for (i, v1), (j, v2) in combinations(enumerate(yhat), 2):
    out.setdefault(i, {})[j] = euclidean(v1, v2)

out
{0: {1: 17.320508075688775, 2: 22.360679774997898, 3: 183.3712082089225, 4: 190.3286631067428}, 
 1: {2: 14.142135623730951, 3: 166.80827317612278, 4: 173.8533865071371}, 
 2: {3: 170.07351351694948, 4: 176.4227876437735}, 
 3: {4: 14.142135623730951}}
```

where out maps to indeces in your input list to the distance between the vectors at those indeces.
You could get the max elements of the vectors whose distance is smaller than the threshold like:

```
for (i, v1), (j, v2) in combinations(enumerate(yhat), 2):
    if euclidean(v1, v2) < threshold:
        out.setdefault(i, {})[j] = (max(v1), max(v2))
out
{0: {1: (220, 230), 2: (220, 230), 3: (220, 300), 4: (220, 300)}, 
 1: {2: (230, 230), 3: (230, 300), 4: (230, 300)}, 
 2: {3: (230, 300), 4: (230, 300)}, 
 3: {4: (300, 300)}}
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. And how can I map those indicies to lists element, and calculate maximum item of each list... its a bit complicated :(